# Multiple problems after connecting and disconnecting to external display via HDMI

Tags: wireless, display, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an ASUS A53S laptop. I connected to a tv via HDMI and everything worked fine. Then I disconnected the HDMI cable and shut off the computer. When I restarted the computer, I had multiple problems:

- The display is the wrong resolution and can't be changed via system settings > display
- Cannot connect to wifi
- The mouse is not working (connects via usb).

I've tried reconnecting the HDMI cable and it does allow me to use the external display, but doesn't change any of the problems. The only display that shows up in system settings > display is "Built-in Display," and I cannot change the resolution. This is different than when I originally connected the HDMI cable, when the external display and the laptop display both showed up and I could use both.

Here's a link to a picture of the system settings > display screen: [http://imgur.com/N5mpfea](https://imgur.com/N5mpfea).

I'm baffled as to why this would have happened or what I could do to fix it so I'd appreciate any input or suggestions.

Comment: I found a temporary fix. When booting, I selected "Advanced options for Ubuntu," and then selected the previous version of the kernal. This completely fixed all the problems and returned my laptop to normal, as far as I can tell. Restarting again with the latest version of the kernal resulted in all the same problems returning.